# Object reference not set to an instance of an object (C#)

Tags: c#

I can't seem to get this working, I'm getting an error once opening my c# project file (.exe) and it says "object reference not set to an instance of an object". Here's the line and the one below it.

```
// Update the actual position

Actor.Position = new Vector3(
                        Actor.PositionToSet.X, 
                        Actor.PositionToSet.Y, 
                        (Math.Round(
                            GetUserStepHeight(
                                Actor.PositionToSet),
                                1)));

Actor.PositionToSet = null;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The possibility is, either 
1. `Actor` is `null` or 
2. `Actor.PositionToSet` is `null`.

To check, either have this:

```
if(Actor == null){
    System.Console.WriteLine("Actor is NULL");
}

if(Actor.PositionToSet == null){
    System.Console.WriteLine("Actor.PositionToSet is NULL");
}
```

or use the LINE BY LINE debugger in Visual Studio.

Here is a piece of advice I got years ago:

1. Think before you code, and build a mental model of the code, then when things break, just reflect on what went wrong without looking at the code.
2. Unit test your code, make it a standard practice of your coding methodology. This will save you years of debugging time.

Comment: well Actor.PositionToSet is null??

Comment: @user2975533 is it NULL? Actor.PositionToSet?

Comment: well the line says Actor.PositionToSet = null; on the next line. the main line is the middle one.

Comment: @user2975533 are you sure, Actor.PositionToSet is not NULL before you set it to NULL? Just asking, add the lines of code I posted, **before** the middle one, and tell me what you see.

Comment: It's working perfectly now, The file used to close when I went over a certain block in my game and it would crash the "Emulator". Now it just shows loads of lines in the console when i go over one :P Thanks though!

Comment: I got another problem still though :/

if (Actor.PositionToSet.X == Item.RoomPosition.X && Actor.PositionToSet.Y == Item.RoomPosition.Y)

                                    {

                                        Session Session = SessionManager.GetSessionByCharacterId(Actor.ReferenceId);
                                        ItemEventDispatcher.InvokeItemEventHandler(Session, Item, this, ItemEventType.Interact, Actor.MoveToAndInteractData);

                                    }



The first line is where the error is, it's the same type.

Comment: @user2975533 it is hard to debug your snippet, without looking at the entire code. Maybe you will want to do it and post it as another question.

Answer (score 0):

Please check that `Actor` or `Actor.PositionToSet` is not null. That is the only reason.

Comment: Sorry but I'm new, how?:S